# Android how to implement card interface similar to Google play store

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am looking to implement a UI similar to the following: 
[image]

I have created a drawable which i use as the background in my list item XML file. Here however, i believe they are using a `GridView`. How can I extrapolate what I did with `ListView` to achieve the same with `GridView`?

Here is my getView() of the gridview adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView iv;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            iv = new ImageView(ctx);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(350,350));
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            iv.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            iv = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        iv.setImageResource(pics[position]);
        return iv;

    }
```

Comment: What you will need to do is inflate a different layout file in getView() of your custom adapter.

Comment: i dont understand.could you give me some code sample/tutorial of how to do it?

Comment: See the answer below for link to a tutorial. Another one: [Custom GridView Android](http://blograchita.wordpress.com/2013/05/04/custom-gridview-android/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView` and `GridView` are basically the same behind the scenes. They both inherit from `AbsListView` and so both have a `getView` method.

Have a look at this tutorial on how to implement `GridView`: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

**EDIT:**

Inside the `getView` method you would inflate your item like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View inflatedView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        inflatedView = new View(context);
        inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistitem, null); 
    } else {
        inflatedView = (View) convertView;
    }
    return inflatedView;
}
```

This is *not* different from how you do it in a `ListView`.

Comment: but in case of gridview, is there something similar to 'list item' as in case of listview, which i can modify?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same XML layout you use for the `ListView` item, but the layout should have width set to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` or `fill_parent`.

Comment: @Darwind Setting the layout's width to `wrap_content` is not required.

Comment: yes so how do i link a particular XML item file to the gridview. And what currently my gridview adapter extends baseadapter, while the listview one extends ArrayAdapter<Level> where i have created the 'level'. Do i need to make any changes there?

Comment: @vikram no you can set it to a specific width as well of course ;-)

Comment: @ShivamBhalla I've added a bit of code to explain what you need to do inside the ´getView`. Bear in mind, this code isn't different from a `ListView`'s `getView` implementation ;-)

Comment: @Darwind I meant that setting the layout's width to `match_parent` or `fill_parent` will work fine as well.